# How to convert a list of Pydantic BaseModels to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pydantic

I can't seem to find any built-in way of simply converting a list of Pydantic BaseModels to a Pandas Dataframe.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd

class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    col1: str
    col2: str

data = [SomeModel(**{'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'})] * 10
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output**

```
>>         0            1
>> 0  (col1, foo)  (col2, bar)
>> 1  (col1, foo)  (col2, bar)
>> ...
```

In this way the columns are loaded as data. A workaround is to do the following

```
pd.DataFrame([model.dict() for model in data])
```

**Output**

```
>>    col1 col2
>> 0  foo  bar
>> 1  foo  bar
>> ...
```

However this method is a bit slow for larger amounts of data. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 34):

A quick and dirty profiling yield the following values:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    col1: int
    col2: str

data = [SomeModel(col1=1,col2="foo"),SomeModel(col1=2,col2="bar")]*4*10**5

import cProfile

cProfile.run( 'pd.DataFrame([s.dict() for s in data])' ) # around 3.4s
cProfile.run( 'pd.DataFrame(jsonable_encoder(data))' ) # around 20.6s
cProfile.run( 'pd.DataFrame([s.__dict__ for s in data])' ) # around 0.59s
cProfile.run( 'pd.DataFrame([dict(s) for s in data])' ) # around 1.1s
cProfile.run( 'pd.DataFrame([vars(s) for s in data])' ) # 0.62s
```

Test run with pydantic 1.10.11 - there exists later [pydantic versions](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/)

Comment: Would it be possible to add `vars(s)` to the comparison (it should be a more pythonic alternative to `s.__dict__` if it's the same performance-wise)?

Comment: note that you can use a generator instead of list comprehension. This should be even faster in all cases

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if it's faster, but [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/) exposes `jsonable_encoder` which essentially performs that same transformation on an arbitrarily nested structure of `BaseModel`:

```
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
pd.DataFrame(jsonable_encoder(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following way

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd

class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    col1: str
    col2: str

data = [SomeModel(**{'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'})] * 10
pd.DataFrame([res.model_dump() for res in data])
```

The main point is iterate the list and transform it to a dictionary with pydantinc built-in function [model_dump](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/)

**Note:**
`.dict()` got converted to `.model_dump()` in newer version of sqlmodel