# How to convert a Pydantic model in FastAPI to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to convert a Pydantic model to a Pandas `DataFrame`,  but I am getting various errors.

Here is the code:

```py
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pickle
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Userdata(BaseModel):
  current_res_month_dec: Optional[int] = 0
  current_res_month_nov:  Optional[int] = 0


async def return_recurrent_user_predictions_gb(user_data: Userdata):

      empty_dataframe =  pd.DataFrame([Userdata(**{
      'current_res_month_dec': user_data.current_res_month_dec,
      'current_res_month_nov': user_data.current_res_month_nov})], ignore_index=True)
```

This is the `DataFrame` that is returned when trying to execute it through `/docs` in my local environment:

```json
Response body
Download
{
  "0": {
    "0": [
      "current_res_month_dec",
      0
    ]
  },
  "1": {
    "0": [
      "current_res_month_nov",
      0
    ]
  }
```

but if I try to use this `DataFrame` for a prediction:

```py
model_has_afternoon = pickle.load(open('./models/model_gbclf_prob_current_product_has_afternoon.pickle', 'rb'))
result_afternoon = model_has_afternoon.predict_proba(empty_dataframe)[:, 1]
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have tried building my own `DataFrame` before, and the predictions should work with a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to convert the Pydantic model into a dictionary using Pydantic's [`dict()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method. Note that other methods, such as Python's `dict()` function and `.__dict__`  attribute, have been found to be *faster* alternatives to Pydantic's `dict()` method (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64700151/17865804)). However, since you are using a Pydantic model, it might be best to use Pydantic's `dict()` method, and then pass the dictionary to [`pandas.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe) surrounded by square brackets; for example, `pd.DataFrame([data.dict()])`. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46577585/17865804), this approach can be used when you need the keys of the passed `dict` to be the *columns* and the values to be the *rows*. If you need to specify a different orientation, you can also use [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-from-dict). Afterwards, you can call `model.predict(df)` to get predictions, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846619/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71612734/17865804).

##### Working Example

```py
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()

class Userdata(BaseModel):
  col1: Optional[int] = 0
  col2:  Optional[int] = 0
  col3:  str = "foo"

@app.post('/submit')
def submit_data(data: Userdata):
    df = pd.DataFrame([data.dict()])
    # pred = model.predict(df)
    return "Success"
```

##### More Options

As you mentioned that you would like to use the `DataFrame` for Machine Learning predictions, it should be noted that there are a few other options to pass the data to `predict()` and `predict_proba()` functions that do not require to create a `DataFrame`. These options include:

```py
model.predict([[data.col1, data.col2, data.col3]])
```

and

```py
model.predict([list(data.dict().values())])
```

Please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849860/17865804) for more details. In case you would also need to respond back to the client with a `DataFrame` in JSON format, please take a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804).