# Getting "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PatientAttendance'" when using Machine Learning in FastAPI

Tags: python, machine-learning, fastapi, predict

I am currently building an API using FastAPI to deploy my logistic regression model. For some reason, I am getting the above error in the server docs when I test the model.

My code below:

```py
app = FastAPI()

class PatientAttendance(BaseModel):
    apptslotduration: int
    patientage: int
    log_distance: float
    pct_appts_missed: float
    doc_no_show_rate: float
    zip_no_show_rate: float
    note_no_show_rate: float
    type_no_show_rate: float
    spec_type_no_show_rate: float
    monthly_no_show_rate: float
    seasonal_no_show_rate: float
    dow_no_show_rate: float
    clinic_no_show_rate: float
    lead_time_in_days: int
    groupedstarttime: int
    priminsurance_no_show_rate: float
    secondinsurance_no_show_rate: float

@app.post('/predict/')
def predict(features: PatientAttendance):
    data = features
    prediction = model.predict([[data]])
    if prediction[0] == 0:
        result = "Patient Show"
    else:
        result = "No-Show"
    probability = model.predict_proba([[data]])

    return {
        'prediction': prediction,
        'probability': probability
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PatientAttendance'
```

I am using a Pydantic BaseModel and I have no idea why I am receiving this error. I believe I have the app pointing in the right direction with respect to the server. I've tried utilizing `GET` & `POST`. `features` is the array of features in my dataset that I standardized and turned into a dictionary. All the features have been vectorized. I always seem to get some type of error whenever I test my API in the server docs.

Comment: You're sending the pydantic basemodel directly into your `predict` function - does that even accept pydantic models directly?

Comment: Yes I believe so. I don't think the problem is with `PatientAttendance`; I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the `def predict(features:` portion.

Comment: The error should have a line number attached, so you can tell exactly where the problem occurs - include that in your question. What is your `model` variable initialized as? If it's a sklearn model, there doesn't seem to be any method (`predict` or `predict_proba`) that expects a pydantic model nested inside two lists.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

```py
# Getting prediction
prediction = model.predict([[data.apptslotduration, data.patientage, data.pct_appts_missed, data.doc_no_show_rate, ...]])[0]

# Getting probability
probability = model.predict_proba([[data.apptslotduration, data.patientage, data.pct_appts_missed, data.doc_no_show_rate, ...]])
```

#### Option 2

Use the [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) method to get the values of all attributes in the model:

```py
# Getting prediction
prediction = model.predict([list(data.__dict__.values())])[0]

# Getting probability
probability = model.predict_proba([list(data.__dict__.values())])
```

or (better) use the Pydantic's [`.dict()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method (in Pydantic V2 [`.dict()` was replaced by `.model_dump()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761451/17865804)):

```py
# Getting prediction
prediction = model.predict([list(data.dict().values())])[0]

# Getting probability
probability = model.predict_proba([list(data.dict().values())])
```

#### Option 3

Convert the input data (from the Pydantic model) into a dictionray using the [`.dict()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method (in Pydantic V2 [`.dict()` was replaced by `.model_dump()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761451/17865804)), and then into a Pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Converting input data into Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([data.dict()])

# Getting prediction
prediction = model.predict(df)[0]

# Getting probability
probability = model.predict_proba(df)
```

#### More Options

In case you have a `list` of inputs, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849860/17865804) (Option 3).