# Can we use Pydantic models (BaseModel) directly inside model.predict() using FastAPI, and if not ,why?

Tags: python, machine-learning, fastapi, prediction, pydantic

I'm using Pydantic model (`Basemodel`) with FastAPI and converting the input into a `dictionary`, and then converting it into a Pandas `DataFrame` to pass it into `model.predict()` function for Machine Learning predictions, as shown below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd
from typing import List

class Inputs(BaseModel):
    f1: float,
    f2: float,
    f3: str

@app.post('/predict')
def predict(features: List[Inputs]):
    output = []

    # loop the list of input features
    for data in features:
         result = {}

         # Convert data into dict() and then into a DataFrame
            data = data.dict()
            df = pd.DataFrame([data])

         # get predictions
            prediction = classifier.predict(df)[0]

         # get probability
            probability = classifier.predict_proba(df).max()

         # assign to dictionary 
            result["prediction"] = prediction
            result["probability"] = probability

         # append dictionary to list (many outputs)
            output.append(result)

    return output
```

It works fine, I'm just not quite sure if it's **optimized** or the right way to do it, since I convert the input two times to get the predictions. Also, I'm not sure if it is going to work **fast** in the case of having a **huge number** of inputs. Any improvements on this? If there's a way (even other than using Pydantic models), where I can work directly and avoid going through conversions and the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use more descriptive names for your variables/objects. For example:

```py
@app.post('/predict')
def predict(inputs: List[Inputs]):
    for i in inputs:
    # ...
```

You cannot pass the Pydantic model directly to the `predict()` function, as it accepts a data `array`, not a Pydantic model. Available options are listed below.

### Option 1

You could use the following (The `i` below represents an item from the `inputs` list):

```py
prediction = model.predict([[i.f1, i.f2, i.f3]])[0]
```

### Option 2

You could use the [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) method to get the values of all attributes in the model and convert them into a `list`:

```py
prediction = model.predict([list(i.__dict__.values())])[0]
```

or, **preferably**, use the Pydantic's [`dict()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method (**Note:** In Pydantic V2 [`dict()` has been replaced by `model_dump()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761451/17865804)):

```py
prediction = model.predict([list(i.dict().values())])[0]
```

### Option 3

Use a Pandas DataFrame as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([i.dict()])
prediction = model.predict(df)[0]
```

### Option 4

You could avoid looping over individual items and calling the `predict()` function multiple times, by using, instead, the below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([i.dict() for i in inputs])
prediction = model.predict(df)
probability = model.predict_proba(df)
return {'prediction': prediction.tolist(), 'probability': probability.tolist()}
```

or (in case you don't wish using Pandas DataFrame):

```py
inputs_list = [list(i.dict().values()) for i in inputs]
prediction = model.predict(inputs_list)
probability = model.predict_proba(inputs_list)
return {'prediction': prediction.tolist(), 'probability': probability.tolist()}
```

Comment: I'm using a list of inputs I don't know how to use this approach in it, recheck my post I updated it with my case (list of inputs and list of outputs)

Comment: Thank you, what if I have many features because in reality I got 40 feature so it'll be exhausting to write them all

Comment: it won't be a waste of memory right? because for reach item I create a dataframe, imagine having 500k items?

Comment: got an error of "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'"

Comment: it works! I was hoping I can get rid of the loop and assign data directly as we normally do with mode.predict

Comment: It’s the same as the previous one, just instead of using a dataframe here there is a list, and dataframes are faster

Comment: `__dict__` is not a method, it is the actual namespace of the class, since the OP is using a pydantic model, they should almost certainly use `data.dict()`