# Getting error "value is not a valid dict" when using Pydantic models in FastAPI for model-based predictions

Tags: python, dataframe, fastapi, prediction, pydantic

I'm trying to use `Pydantic` models with FastAPI to make multiple predictions (for a list of inputs). The problem is that one can't pass Pydantic models directly to `model.predict()` function, so I converted it to a dictionary, however, I'm getting the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dict'`

My code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()

class Inputs(BaseModel):
    id: int
    f1: float
    f2: float
    f3: str

class InputsList(BaseModel):
    inputs: List[Inputs]

@app.post('/predict')
def predict(input_list: InputsList):
    df = pd.DataFrame(input_list.inputs.dict())
    prediction = classifier.predict(df.loc[:, df.columns != 'id'])
    probability = classifier.predict_proba(df.loc[:, df.columns != 'id'])
    return {'id': df["id"].tolist(), 'prediction': prediction.tolist(), 'probability': probability.tolist()}
```

I have also a problem with the **return**, I need the output to be something like :

```py
    [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "prediction": "class1",
        "probability": 0.89
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "prediction": "class3",
        "probability": 0.45
      }
    ]
```

PS: the `id` in `Inputs` class doesn't take place in the prediction (is not a feature), but I need it to be shown next to its prediction (to reference it).

**Request**:
[image]

Comment: The code you posted is _not_ valid Python code, even when the indentations were fixed. Please update your code so that it can be run and post the full error that you are getting including the traceback.

Comment: @PaulP I updated the post with a picture f the error in FastAPI

Comment: How are you calling the endpoint? (Also, please try not to post screenshots but rather the actual content as text.)

Comment: @PaulP I'm using http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs for testing the API, the error is : {
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
      "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: What did you type in? Does it also say `application/json` on the right hand side?

Comment: @PaulP yes it does, please recheck my post for screenshot update regarding it

Comment: You have a comma at the end of both `"f3": "test",`. This isn't valid JSON, which might be why it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, there are unecessary commas `,` at the end of both `f1` and `f2` attributes of your schema, as well as in the `JSON` payload you are sending. Hence, your schema should be:

```py
class Inputs(BaseModel):
    id: int
    f1: float
    f2: float
    f3: str
```

**Second**, the `422` error is due to that the `JSON` payload you are sending does not match your schema. As noted by @MatsLindh your `JSON` payload should look like this:

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "f1": 1.0,
      "f2": 1.0,
      "f3": "text"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "f1": 2.0,
      "f2": 2.0,
      "f3": "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Third**, you are creating the DataFrame in the worng way. You are attempting to call the `dict()` method on a `list` object; hence, the `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dict'`. Instead, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849860/17865804), you should call the `.dict()` method on each item in the `list`, as shown below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([i.dict() for i in input_list.inputs])
```

**Finally**, to return the results in the output format mentioned in your question, use the below. **Note** `predict_proba()` returns an array of lists containing the class probabilities for the `input`. If you would like to return only the `probability` for a specific class, use the index for that class instead, e.g., `prob[0]`.

```py
results = []
for (id, pred, prob) in zip(df["id"].tolist(), prediction.tolist(), probability.tolist()):
    results.append({"id": id, "prediction": pred, "probability": prob})
return results
```

alternatively, you can use a DataFrame and call its [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method to convert it into a dictionary, as shown below. If you have a large amount of data and find the approach below being quite slow in returning the results, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) for alternative approaches.

```py
results = pd.DataFrame({'id': df["id"].tolist(),'prediction': prediction.tolist(),'probability': probability.tolist()})
return results.to_dict(orient="records")
```

If you would like to return only the `probability` for a specific class when using DataFrame, you could extract it and add it to a new `list` like this `prob_list = [item[0] for item in probability.tolist()]` or using [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) like this `prob_list = list(map(itemgetter(0), probability.tolist()))`, and use that `list` instead when creating the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of the input schema for the view function does not match the content you're sending:

```py
class Inputs(BaseModel):
    id: int
    f1: float
    f2: float
    f3: str

class InputsList(BaseModel):
    inputs: List[Inputs]
```

This matches a request body in the format of:

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "f1": 1.0,
      "f2": 1.0,
      "f3": "foo"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "f1": 2.0,
      "f2": 2.0,
      "f3": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

The request body you're sending does not match the expected format, and thus, you get an 422 response back.

Either change the object you're sending to match the format expected by FastAPI or drop the `InputsList` wrapper and set the input as `input_list: List[Inputs]` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it does solve the error 422, but another error occurred saying : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dict' , either using InputsList or input_list: List[Inputs] directly

Comment: please recheck my post for updated issue